# AdControl An unexpected error occurred during call to the ad source (Name: CNTX).}

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, ads

i use Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight and i would insert an AdControl into project.
Receive errors:
An unexpected error occurred during call to the ad source (Name: CNTX).}

this is my xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Open New page" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="advertising" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="480" Height="80">
        <UI:AdControl Grid.Row="1" ApplicationId="test_client" AdUnitId="Image480_80" Height="80" Name="AdControlMain" Width="480" IsAutoCollapseEnabled="True" Margin="0,-2" AdRefreshed="AdControlMain_AdRefreshed" ErrorOccurred="AdControlMain_ErrorOccurred" />

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I've been getting the same error for the past few days on a WP 8.1 Silverlight project as well. It even happens when creating a fresh project. I believe it may be a server-side bug on Microsoft's side.

Comment: I think so too. I'm reporting it on the forum msdn. I hope will be resolved

Comment: today it works. probably was a problem microsoft